# Asking for Remote Notifications Authorization at another time in app's life cycle?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, usernotifications

I'm running into a strange problem. When I request for remote notifications authorization inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions using the below code, I'm able to get a push remote notification from my server (Firebase Messaging) but when I try to request for authorization at later time **NOT INSIDE didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** I'm not able to get any notification.

**I don't want to ask for authorisations at the launch time. I want to ask for authorization after the user have logged in for example.**

Apple documentation says:

> Always call this method before scheduling any local notifications and
>   before registering with the Apple Push Notification Service.
>   Typically, you call this method at launch time when configuring your
>   app's notification support. However, you may call it at another time
>   in your app's life cycle, providing that you call it before performing
>   any other notification-related tasks.

```
 // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
 UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

 let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]

 UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })

 UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Any suggestion/solution to this problem?

App Info:
Deployment Target: iOS 10.3
iOS Devices: iPhone 6 with iOS 10 / iPhone 7 with iOS 11

Comment: where's the other point you call it at?

Comment: what do you mean?!

Comment: where else do you request for authorization again? Also just curious why do you need to register it again at a later time? Or want to register it at a later time

Comment: Also, maybe try seeing if  `application(_:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:)` can help you out too

Comment: @TPN1994 I'm requesting from inside a user action handler. I'm not requesting again! I just don't want to ask for authorisations at the launch time. didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is successfully called

Comment: what does the below line print NSLog(@"APNs token retrieved: %@", deviceToken) , pls share some more code what and where you are trying

Comment: FWIW you know you can call `UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()` anytime you like right? And the user would NEVER know!

Answer (score 2):

So Here's how I solved it:

In my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I register for remote notification like so:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

and then at later time, for example after the user have logged in, I ask for the authorization by calling the method below;

```
 func reqeust()  {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in



        })

    }
```

Comment: So you actually call `requestAuthorization` after `registerForRemoteNotifications`, despite what the documentation says. Did you get the tokens this way?

Comment: I'm using Firebase remote notifications, so I got it anyway even if the user didn't requestAuthorization. If you are not using Firebase then I think once you requestAuthorization you will get it.